# Outputting POST data into <<<'EOT'

Tags: php, content-management-system, fwrite, eot

I'm making a content management system. I'm allowing the user to post a few bits of information through a form which will then be used on the new page (such as 'page title' and 'carousel speed'), but I'm struggling to get that information into the generated page.

To add the content of the site I'm using `$page .= <<<'EOT'` and placing the html in there, but trying to echo `$_POST` variables within this means that the PHP code will literally appear as I write it inside the EOT and not as a result.

Is there a way to tell the EOT to treat the `<?php echo $_POST['speed'] ?>` as an exception?

```
<?php

    $addTo = $_POST['addTo'];
    //$visit = $_POST['visit'];
    $dir = $_POST['name'];
    $desc = $_POST['desc'];

    $dir = preg_replace('/\s+/', '_', $dir);

    mkdir($addTo.'/'.$dir, 0777);
    mkdir($addTo.'/'.$dir.'/photos', 0777);

    //Make page
    $content = "he";
    $myfile = fopen ($addTo.'/'.$dir.'/index.php', "w") or die ("Unable to open file!");
    $page = "";
    $speed = $_POST['speed'];



$page .= <<<'EOT'

<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.min.js" integrity="sha256-cCueBR6CsyA4/9szpPfrX3s49M9vUU5BgtiJj06wt/s=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/2c6a42bed3.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

    <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
      <!-- Indicators -->
      <ol class="carousel-indicators" style="display:none">
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="3"></li>
      </ol>

      <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
      <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">

        <?php

            $active = "active";
            $url = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'].'photos/';
            //echo $url." - url<br/>";

            $conn = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","test");

            $sql = "SELECT speed FROM pages WHERE title = ''";

            if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();}
            $sql = "SELECT * FROM photos WHERE url = '$url'"; 

            $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

            while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
                ?> 
                    <div class="item <?=$active?>">
                        <img src="<?php echo $row['url'].$row['caption']; ?>">
                    </div> 
                <?php

                $active="";

            }

            $conn->close();

        ?>

      </div>

      <!-- Left and right controls -->
      <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
      </a>
      <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
      </a>
    </div>




</body>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
         $("#myCarousel").carousel({
             interval : 420,
             pause: false
         });
    });
</script>

%s

EOT;


?> 
<?php

    $output = sprintf($page, $speed);
    echo $output;

    fwrite($myfile, $page);
    fclose($myfile);

    $conn = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","test");

    if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();}

    $sql = "INSERT INTO pages (title, type, description, active, speed) VALUES ('$dir', '$addTo','$desc' , '1', '$speed')";

    if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
        echo "New record created successfully";
    } else {
        echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
    }

    $conn->close();

    //Redirect
    if (isset($visit)){
        //header('Location:index.php?newPage='.$addTo.'/'.$dir.'/'.$filename);
    }

    else {
        //header('Location:index.php?newPage='.$addTo.'/'.$dir.'/'.$filename);
    }

?>
```

Comment: how about you concatenate in your php echo statement. Its easy. <?php echo ' ..................................................... '. $_POST['speed']. ....  '; You can write as many lines of php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way to tell the EOT to treat the `<?php echo` as an
>   exception?

No there isn't, unless  you replace `'EOT'` with `"EOT"`. The first one (what you're currently using) treats everything as a raw string.  The second one works just as double-quotes in PHP, so the string will be parsed and variables will be recognized.

I would keep using `'EOT'` as you are, and insert placeholders `%s` in the string.  Then I'd use `sprintf` to replace the placeholders with values ([see the docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php))

```
// the %s will be replaced later with your values
$template = <<< 'EOT'
The car has speed %s and a mileage of %s ...
EOT;

//build the args. Use htmlspecialchars to protect your users from
// Cross-Site Scripting attacks
$args = [
    htmlspecialchars($_POST['speed']),
    htmlspecialchars($_POST['mileage']),
    ...
];

//insert the args into the template
$output = sprintf($template, ...$args);

echo $output;
```

**security note:** Because you output strings the user sent you back to the browser, you are vulnerable to [Cross-Site Scripting (XSS) attacks](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-site_Scripting_(XSS)): a user can get your website to execute any code she wants since you're using her input to build the page.  I cleaned the inputs with `htmlspecialchars()` to protect you.

Comment: Thanks for this. When I echo the $output after putting it through sprintf it shows a very broken version of what the page should actually look like (but with the %s showing as the $_POST value as it should), is there a way I can just throw the output number into the actual EOT without  this happening? I feel like there's one little step I'm missing. Thanks again.

Comment: @ERushforth I can't say why it's not working without seeing your code. I suggest adding it as an update to the question and explaining what's wrong there.

Comment: Thanks, just edited the code in there. Right now I've put %s at the bottom just before the EOT but It'll be replacing '420' in that <script>, and I'll be re-adding the security once this works!

Comment: @ERushforth You're not using the strategy as I do in my answer. `EOT` is meant to be string only, and the placeholder `%s` will be replaced with the parameters you used in `sprintf`.  You're putting PHP code and even DB queries inside your `EOT` string. That won't work.

Comment: @ERushforth Just to be clear: if you're trying to do what I showed, then inside the `'EOT'` there cannot be any PHP code.  Only a string with placeholders.

Comment: If that's the case I might need to rethink how to create the pages, they're going to contain a lot of mixed code and EOT is probably not the solution. Thanks for all your help, I'll mark this as an answer seeing as you technically answered what I asked, and it'll be useful for others.